# Restrict the TAB key on accessory keyboards

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a `UIScrollView` with 2 `view`s, side by side, each of which covers the entire screen.
They are moved to visible bounds on user's action, only one covering the screen at a time. Both of these views have multiple `UITextFields`. Working with the simulator, I fill in a `textField` in the first view and when I press the Tab key, the `firstResponder` is assigned to a `textField` in the other view. I understand that on using the device, the user will not be able to do that. But what if the user uses a bluetooth keyboard, or similar accessory? I do not want a textField, that is currently not visible to become `firstResponder`. Can this be done?

EDIT: I just remembered the `canBecomeFirstResponder` method. But how do I determine which `textField` is about to `becomeFirstResponder`?

Comment: Is bluetooth keyboard can be attach with iPhone device ??? Strange!!

Comment: There are many keyboard accessories out there for iPhones, aren't there ? Like [these](http://ipod.about.com/od/introductiontotheiphone/tp/keyboards-for-iphone.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the problem isn't that they shouldn't be able to tab between the two text fields, but instead that they shouldn't be able to edit a text field that isn't visible, and they should be able to tab between them if they are both visible at the same time.

Instead of restricting tab, I would implement the UITextField delegate method -textFieldShouldBeginEditing:, which allows you to return a boolean whether or not that text field should become the first responder.

Something such as:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //  Only edit if the text field is visible
    return !textField.isHidden;
}
```

You may need to adjust this code to fit your 'is visible' status of the text field.

Comment: Probably the silliest thing I have ever been stuck on.
Thank you. `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is exactly what i needed.